# How works redux store for big application

Tags: javascript, redux

How to organize store which contains a lot of data?
I imagine it like this. There is entities section where stored data like in database and section with data for pages. Items from pages references to entities. Is it good decision?

```
const store = {
    entities: {
        posts: {
            0: { /* ... */ },
            1: { /* ... */ },
            2: { /* ... */ }
        }
    },
    pages: {
        allPosts: {
            items: [0, 1, 2] // ids from entities
        },
        onePost: {
            id: 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the recommended approach, e.g., http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data

Comment: Agreed. Looks good

Comment: Yeah it's a good approach